# Show a cone isn't a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that a cone isn't a regular surface because I can't construct a chart with cts partial derivatives at its tip. But can anyone show me this last step rigorously? Why would any chart for the tip have a discontinuous partial derivative?

Comment: Consider the the absolute value function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Why is that not differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Because the limits from +infinite and -infinite of the definition of the derivative are not equal. I suppose the same is true for the cone, I wonder if just stating that is sufficient in an exam...

Comment: It's the same idea. To make it exactly like the absolute value function, just consider the partial derivative with respect to a single variable like $x$. Also, the two limits to consider are not from "+infinite and -infinite" but the limit as we approach zero from the positive side and the negative side.